# VB Application icon

Tags: vb.net, icons

My application icon does not show high density version while changing folder view settings that contains my application, however my icon contains 32, 48, 64, 96, 128 pixels.
Any help please?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a 256x256 pixel version in your icon file.

Windows doesn't use 96x96 or 128x128 pixel icons, and the 32x32 and 48x48 pixel versions are only used when those sizes are called for in the UI. They are not scaled upwards because the result would be pixellated and horrible-looking.

The *minimum* icon versions that must be provided in a Windows ICO file are:

- 256x256, 32-bit color (PNG compressed)
- 48x48, 32-bit color
- 32x32, 32-bit color
- 16x16, 32-bit color
- 48x48, 24-bit color
- 32x32, 24-bit color
- 16x16, 24-bit color

You can include the other sizes if you want. It won't hurt anything. And there might be components in the shell or elsewhere that use those sizes. I can't remember all the rules, [they're too complicated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn742485.aspx). But larger versions of the icon will always be scaled down when the exact size is not provided.

If your application needs to be accessible in "Safe Mode" or somewhere where only the lowest common denominator of video drivers will be available, I also recommend including 8-bit or 4-bit color versions of your icons. Don't spend too much time on them, though; use an icon editor that can automatically generate them, and then clean them up if necessary just so that they're recognizable. And you only need these low-bit-depth icons for the small sizes.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. Thank you very much Cody Gray